# Ruby on Rails: Entering data from another database into a new database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, submit

I have two databases in my app. One is Projects, that holds data on projects created in the app and another is User that I made when installing the Devise gem that holds the usernames and passwords of all the people that can use the app.

I have a page where the user can create a new project to be submitted into the database.

I am trying to get the `:username` field data of the current user from the User database to be submitted along with the data they enter to a new field called `username_project`.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "form" %>


<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>

<%= f.select( :username_project, User.all.map {|p| [p.:username]}) %>


<%= f.submit "Create New Project", :class => "button" %>


<% end %>
```

At the moment, there is a drop down that shows the Usernames stored in the database, but I am trying to get the `<%= current_user.username %>` value to be submitted as the username_project value, when the user hits submit. I am new to rails so go easy on me. Thanks in advance.

Update:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "form" %>


    <%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>

<%= current_user.username %>
<%= f.hidden_field :username_project, :value => current_user.username %>

<%= f.submit "Create New Project", :class => "button" %>


    <% end %>
```

Comment: Do you want `username_project` select to be set `current_user.username` be default OR you want to sent `:username_project=current_user.username` without showing select in form?

Comment: :username_project=current_user.username without showing select in the form please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [hidden_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field) helper:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "form" %>

<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :username_project, :value => current_user.username %>
  <%= f.submit "Create New Project", :class => "button" %>
<% end %>
```